# Cannot see IplImage in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, opencv, iplimage

I'm trying to display a 3D scene(OpenGL-OpenCV) in a QGraphicsView object in QT. The scene has 5 planes: top, bottom, right, left and front. I'm taking images from my webcam and mapping them to the front plane. I have successfully displayed 4 of 5 planes, the front plane is missing.

I followed this tutorial to load the OpenGL scene: http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html

However, I don't know how to treat the IplImage to be displayed in the QT Object. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I salvaged out of a blog posting,
This will provide you with a QImage that you can display using Qt.
you should tailor it to fit your needs.

```
QImage img;


constructor()
{
// setup capture device
CvCapture *cvCapture = cvCreateCapture(0);
}


getQImageFromIplImage()
{
// this frame gets a frame from capture device
IplImage *frame = new IplImage();
frame = cvQueryFrame(cvCapture);

// create an IplImage with 8bit color depth
IplImage *iplImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width, frame->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

// copy image captured from capture device to new image, converting pixel data from OpenCV's default BGR format to Qt's RGB format
cvCvtColor(frame, iplImg, CV_BGR2RGB);

// create a this newly converted RGB pixel data with a QImage
qImg = QImage((uchar *)iplImg->imageData, iplImg->width, iplImg->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
}
```

for full code, check out:
http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/03/05/qt-opencv-combined-for-face-detecting-qwidgets/